# Passing data in a segmented Controller?

Tags: ios, swift

I got stuck because one ViewController trying to pass data from one ViewController to another. To explain my code is that I have label in `mainViewController` named `name1` with data inside of it and I am trying to pass that data that is in text format to the `name2` label in the `firstViewController` of `name2` label, Can you please help me with it.
Thank you in advance

```
   class mainViewController: UIViewController {
   //its inside a segment controller 
   @objc func Seg(sender: UISegmentedControl) {

    switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
   let firstViewController = SharedViewController()
        print(self.name1.text!)

        firstViewController.name2.text = self.name1.text!
        self.addChild(firstViewController)

        self.bottomContainer.addSubview(firstViewController.view)

        firstViewController.didMove(toParent: self)
  default: 
        let secondViewController = Shared2ViewController()
        self.addChild(secondViewController)
        self.bottomContainer.addSubview(secondViewController.view)
        secondViewController.didMove(toParent: self)
 }
```

Comment: You posted a small part of code, it is difficult to be sure of what you did. How do you transition from Main to Shared ? If on segue, then you should pass data in prepare. Otherwise, you can use delegation to update firstViewController from MainViewController (class name should start with Uppercase). But here, you create a new instance SharedViewController that will not exist anymore when you leave the function where it is created.

Comment: so what should I do?

Comment: Show more code, it is very hard to give sure advice otherwise. And tell: how do you transition between controllers ?

Comment: I have added more code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to manipulate another view controller's views directly. That violates the principle of encapsulation and often doesn't work (as in this case.)

You should add a string property to the other view controller, and install that string into the label text in `viewWillAppear`.

Also note that creating a view controller with an init like `SharedViewController()` doesn't usually do what you want. (You won't get the view controller's views loaded from it's storyboard/xib.) You usually want to use the Storyboard instantiate method, or to load it from the XIB.

Comment: Thank you for the advice